# How to switch to external display when screen is locked

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, suspend, lock-screen

When the laptop is sleeping and connected to the docking station (lid closed), I click the dock's external power button.

From the physical indication lights I see that the laptop awakens but see nothing in the external monitor.

I try super+p, but nothing happens (works when the screen isn't locked).

I "blindly" type the password, then super+p, then see the screen on the external monitor already unlocked.

**Is there a way to switch to external monitor when the screen is locked?** Thanks.

Comment: Is the question still valid?

Comment: Still happening sometimes.